# The offline version repl.it

Tags: javascript, github

Not sure if I am putting my question correctly - Is it possible to have an offline version of [repl.it](http://repl.it) (only JavaScript required), so that it can be used without internet access?

Comment: You mean, installing those languages on your local machine?

Comment: actually I need to discuss some concepts  of JavaScript with my team but offline. Yes I only need JavaScript.

Comment: Can't you just type into your browser's console?

Comment: @bjb568, yes thats certainly an option. But I am looking for offline repl.it

Comment: Can't you just open up the page and don't close it?

Comment: Why dont you just install https://github.com/replit/jsrepl on localhost?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're looking to install a way to run a JavaScript REPL on your local machine, you have two options:

- Open your browser's console as usual.  Lack of internet doesn't make it any less JavaScripty.
- Install [NodeJS](http://nodejs.org/)

Comment: I am well aware of the JavaScript console to be an option. The problem is the default browser the team has is IE-8, and installing higher versions or any other browser won't be an option due to their IT policy. That's why I am looking for a better offline tool like repl.it

Comment: The node REPL didnt struck my mind. Thanks for your time to answer me.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a text editor that can run a dos command, you can use CScript.exe, the windows version of a javascript engine. Though beware, that this is not ES5 compatible, and there is no browser object. Writing to stdout can be done using CScript.Echo()

I use TextPad which has a tools configuration, in which you can set the CScript path (find it in your windows system directory).

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why can't you do to create your own **REPL** instead, you just have to create a new `window.open("", "_Jres", "", "false")` you can also have `window.open("", "_self")` to replace the current document.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Js Execute</title></head>
<body>    
    <textarea id="code" rows="10" cols="50">
//write your code here
alert("Clicking OK will write heading 1 in the new window");
document.write("<h1>heading 1</h1>");
    </textarea>
    <br/>
    <button onclick="Execute()">Click To execute the above written JS</button>
    <script>
        function Execute() {
            var win2 = window.open("", "_Jres", "", "false");
            var content = document.getElementById("code");
            var datacode = content.value;
            console.log(datacode);
            var hbody = "<script>" + datacode + "</" + "script>";
            win2.document.writeln(hbody);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [RunJS](https://runjs.app/).
The free version can be used as a better REPL or an editor for testing small scripts.
The paid version is worth it with extra themes, tabs and ability to import third party packages.